# Two clicks for action to be performed?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I am trying to create a `JButton` that is disabled by default. When the user clicks on a row in a `JTable`, I want the button to become enabled. The problem is I have multiple `JTables` and I need the button to become disabled again once another table tab is clicked on.
For some reason it takes two clicks of a `Jtable` tab to disable the `Jbutton`.

Here are two examples of my action listeners which enable the button:

```
jtblSunLessons.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btnDelLesson.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
});

jtblMonLessons.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btnDelLesson.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my method to disable the button when another tab is clicked:

```
private void jTabbedPane1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    btnDelLesson.setEnabled(false);
    jtblSunLessons.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    jtblMonLessons.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
}
```

I have tried to find out what is wrong but I can't find any solution to this. How can I fix this?

Comment: 1) *Here is my method to disable the button when another tab is clicked:* - use a `ChangeListener` instead of the MouseListener. An event will be generated when the tab is changed. 2) there is no need to us invokeLater() in your ListSelectionListener. Code invoked from a listener is executed on the EDT. I'm not un derstanding why you only have a single button, but you have two tables. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr Okay thank you will do. Do you think the invokeLater could actually cause the problem? I'm new to coding so my understanding is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the listener is incorrect. The invokeLater() is unneeded as well (thanks camickr). Here is my corrected code:

````
        ListSelectionModel model2 = jtblSunLessons.getSelectionModel();
        model2.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
                if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                    return;
                }
                ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
                
                if(lsm.isSelectionEmpty()){
                    btnDelLesson.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else{
                    btnDelLesson.setEnabled(true);
                }
            
            }
        });```

I disabled the button at the beginning of the code and reset the button to disabled inside the tabbed panes' actionPerformed. Also make sure to clearSelection for each table in the actionPerformed.
````